# Icecast 2 ~ use pls or m3u on a listen.mp3 from caster.fm

Tags: icecast, internet-radio, m3u, pls-file

Today I decided to make a Online Radio Station using a free account on caster.fm. I decided that it wasn't anything to do with them and it was more to do with general Icecast 2.

I own a game server and there is a plugin to allow radio streams but in the format of M3U & PLS playlists not stream files. I know you can mount the stream onto the PLS/M3U but, it doesn't seem to work. I added this to a file I called listen.pls:

```
   [playlist] File1=http://shaincast.caster.fm:port/listen.mp3 Title1= Velocity FM
```

The port is specified in actual file.

But it doesn't seem to work. I understand PLS is only a playlist, could this be the cause?

Comment: "I decided that it wasn't anything to do with them" - what wasn't anything to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

You need some line breaks in your file.  I'd also make sure you don't have a space after your equals sign... parsers for these INI-style files vary and can be a bit finicky sometimes.

```
[playlist]
File1=http://shaincast.caster.fm:80/listen.mp3
Title1=Velocity FM
```

You could also switch to M3U which is more broadly compatible (but it sounds like in your case you can handle either):

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Velocity FM
http://shaincast.caster.fm:80/listen.mp3
```